# Getting images from rtsp in C#

Tags: c#, rtsp

I have an IP camera and I have it's rtsp link. I wan't to capture it's images continuously in C# and store them at a specific Folder. I have searched but mostly people have done through http request, no one has used rtsp. Anyone who has done it through rtsp in C#?

Comment: check this, it may help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nager.VideoStream](https://github.com/nager/Nager.VideoStream) is based on ffmpeg and can therefore easily be used across platforms. If you are use the `NewImageReceived` event you can save every Frame to a specific Folder.

```
PM> install-package Nager.VideoStream
```

```cs
var inputSource = new StreamInputSource("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov");
//var inputSource = new WebcamInputSource("Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000");

var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

var client = new VideoStreamClient();
client.NewImageReceived += NewImageReceived;
var task = client.StartFrameReaderAsync(inputSource, OutputImageFormat.Bmp, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
//Console.ReadLine();
client.NewImageReceived -= NewImageReceived;

private static void NewImageReceived(byte[] imageData)
{
    File.WriteAllBytes($@"{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.bmp", imageData);
}
```